# Can anyone tell me what this is?

Tags: species-identification, species

On my one plants, this green worm is all over it, with white and yellow cocoons on the Leaves.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Where is the worm again? Do you have any pictures?

Comment: looks like a cocoon. Without the location and a picture of the actual worm, this is like searching for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Please add your location, size of the white and yellow masses in your picture, and info about the green worm (size, pictures would be very helpful). Thanks

Comment: The green worm is inside the cocoon, I'll see if I can find one.  Leduc, Alberta, Canada

Comment: There is the worm, can't post anymore of them cause of size limit

Comment: You should keep the first picture of the worm and the old picture of the cocoon! as @theforestecologist said, we could need the size of the worm and cocoon.

Comment: Would it help to have a ruler in the picture so u can see wat the size of it is?